# Where to get the nerwork-map-<Version>.jar for corda network setup for the Community edition?

Tags: corda

I have been try to setup the network map. Where can we get the network-map.jar to run the standalone network mapper for community edition.

Or Network map only comes with enterprise version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no community version of the network map provided by R3.

However, as Sneha mentioned there is a commercial offering called CENM (https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.2.html). It's not just a Network Map but also takes care of other aspects of Network Management like Identity and Signing.

In case you are looking for an open-source network map you could try out Cordite Network Map
(https://marketplace.r3.com/solutions/cordite-network-map) developed by one of our partners.

Answer (score 0):

in open source version, network maps functionality is handled by adding the node-info files to each node's additional-node-infos folder.

If you want to run a stand-alone network map, one option is to use CENM - Corda Enterprise Network Manager. With CENM you get access to the pki-tool, identity manager and network map jars which helps you to set up a private network.

https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.1/network-map.html

Apart from that if you wish to experiment with a standalone network map, you could also try out a stand-alone network map built by one of our engineers. Pasting the link below

https://github.com/roastario/spring-boot-network-map